# UNIX - How can I highlight file content with pattern in another file?

Tags: bash, grep

I want to use `grep --color -E '^|pattern1|pattern2' file name` for highlight parts of my file, but patterns are in another files. for example:

base file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env
<?php 
include 'second.php';
function saybye()
{
    return "bye";
}
echo "<br />";
function sayHello() {
   return "hellobye";
}
?>
```

pattern file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env
<?php 
include 'second.php';
function saybye()
{
    return "bye";
}
echo "<br />";
?>
```

I want to highlight parts of base file that exact match with pattern file.

also I want to highlight lines with different colors. how can I do this?

thanks for any help.

Comment: See grep‘s option `-f`.

Comment: @Cyrus : I use grep -f options but it removes or doesn't show return "hellobye"; in base file!.